# Is there any IOS app have some kind of example about hint User to flat Device?

Tags: ios

I want to create a view in my app that guides the user to lay their device horizontal, as if it was sitting on top of a table or a desk. Is there any existing app that has an example of this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "flat device"? Hold the device in a particular way?

Comment: yes I need user to realize -----

lay the device horizontal to ground----is there any app have some kind of hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are apps in the App Store that simulate a [level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_level) using the accelerometer or gyroscope to determine device orientation. Also, I think that the Super Monkey Ball game had a control calibration mode that asked the user to hold the device in a particular position.

Comment: OK   thanks for your help!

I'll go checking this app about it's hint